# Initializing a private collection in a constructor, repeat or use chaining?

Tags: c#

I have a class like:

```
public class Something
{
   private Dictionary<int,int> dic;

   public Something() 
   {
         dic = new Dictionary<int,int>();
   }

   public Something(Dictionary<int,int> a)
  {
         dic = new Dictionary<int,int>();

   }

}
```

How can I avoid initializing the collection twice?

Comment: You can chain that if you want, the compiler can inline it. Btw, what are you doing with the parameter "a"?

Comment: @Theraot the parameter a was just for convey my situation, I am using it for things in my real code.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are looking for [chaining constructor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/271582/Constructor-Chaining-in-Csharp):

```
public class Something
{
    private Dictionary<int, int> dic;

    public Something()
        : this(new Dictionary<int, int>())
    {
    }

    public Something(Dictionary<int, int> a)
    {
        dic = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Both this and D Stanley's answers are good.  I think this is slightly better for this case because it uses good defaults which is not redundant.  It's also more expressive IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Call `this()`:

```
public Something() 
{
      dic = new Dictionary<int,int>();
}

public Something(Dictionary<int,int> a) : this()
{
     // do something with a??
}
```

note that the "default" constructor is NOT called by default form other constructors, so you're not really initializing the dictionary *twice*.

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative:

```
public class Something
{
    private Dictionary<int, int> dic;

    private void Initialize()
    {
        dic = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    }

    public Something()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public Something(Dictionary<int, int> a)
    {
        Initialize();
        // do something with a??
        // Yes, you are not using the parameter "a".
        // I don't know if this is intentional.
    }
}
```

**Note:** this wont work for `readonly` fields.

---

By the way, as [I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549880/initializing-a-private-collection-in-a-constructor-repeat-or-use-chaining#comment30730755_20549880) you can [chain the constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20549913/402022). The compiler can optimize it.